# Which CMS to use?

Tags: xml, content-management-system, templates

I need to create a web (or non-web) system where a user can create a template layout with tags and placeholders for elements. They could then add new pages to this template. My system would need to pick up any elements that have changed and create an XML of the tagged content. I was just wondering what would be the best CMS or any other software I could use  to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Open Source CMS](http://php.opensourcecms.com/)

It is a site that has numerous CMS demo's available that you can try out.

With this you can have a look at some or all of the available packages and choose the one that best suite your needs